A variational problem from physics / quantum mechanics?
I look at the problem of minimizing the functional $(a, b > 0$)
$$\int_{\mathbb R} (a x^2 f(x)^2 + b f'(x)^2)dx$$ over $L^2$ functions with ($L^2$-)norm $1$.
The solution is Gaussian but I do not remember where that problem comes from. I think quantum mechanics. Could you help me recall the origin of that problem?

Answer clear now?

Your expression $$\int_{\mathbb R}dx~ (a x^2 f(x)^2 + b f'(x)^2)$$
is just the expectation value of the energy of the SHQ oscillator, for $\psi=f$, $b=\hbar^2/2m$, and $a= m\omega^2/2$.
Its minimum is evidently at the familiar ground state Gaussian, $f =\sqrt[4]{m\omega/\pi\hbar}~ \exp( -m\omega x^2/2\hbar)$, suitably normalized to norm one. Observe the normalization is $\sqrt[8]{a/b\pi^2}$.
